# Getting a lot of old feeds from Stack Overflow

Tags: support, feed

I'm getting a lot of feeds from Stack Overflow questions. I'm subscribed to them, but the feeds are old. I'm getting 100 every 5 minutes.

Does anybody know why, or what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

See this bug report with the associated change:

[Prevent title edits to spawn a new RSS post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18051/prevent-title-edits-to-spawn-a-new-rss-post/22713)

basically the `<id>` field changed so it's not affected by question title changes any more.